# Why are the cars right-hand drive in Umbrella Academy?

Tags: the-umbrella-academy

In watching Season 3 of The Umbrella Academy, I've noticed that for many (if not all) of the vehicles the driver sits on the right side. Given that this season was filmed in Canada and is implied to take place in North America, this doesn't make much sense. Is there ever a reason given for the reversed vehicles, either in- or out-of-universe?

Answer (score 7):

There's a theory out there that goes as such: The Toyota Century is the model the Umbrellas drive for the entire season, but there is a very solid reason for it. If you've seen far enough in you have seen the Hotel Oblivion on the other side from Obsidian, the Hotel Oblivion is 100% Japanese. And because the Obsidian was built by Reginald to mirror the Oblivion, he chose the Centuries as a nod to the other side, essentially the Japanese version of his car (Rolls Royce Silver Wraith).

The Umbrellas, as far as I know, are the only ones driving cars with the steering wheel on the right side.  I've never seen or heard (or found online) anything that indicates a canon answer, but they're definitely driving Toyota Centuries.

Comment: They did make a small run of LHD Centurys, but for 'special' occasions, shows etc. the car was never actually made for export, hence the predominance of RHD models.

Comment: I've watched the entire third season and I tried paying attention to see if other cars were RHD or LHD. Couldn't make out anything (or maybe I just didn't notice). Are all the cars RHD or just the cars the Umbrellas drive?

Comment: Wow this is old but I'm just yet watching Umbrella Academy. The Umbrella children are all driving right-handed cars. In season 3 Reginald is driving his Rolls Royce on the left hand side (while I was expecting a British car to have the steering wheel on the right). But in season 1 Hazel was also driving the Volvo with a steering wheel on the right side.